# COVID-19: Natural infection compared to vaccination

Tags: covid-19

It is often stated that getting infected gives a lesser immunological protection from covid, than a vaccine, but studying [immunology.org](https://www.immunology.org/coronavirus/connect-coronavirus-public-engagement-resources/covid-immunity-infection-vaccine) - I'm getting the feeling that the immunization is merely more variable (not so good if the infection was mild),

I'm also not understanding how a vaccine developed against the first variants of covid protects better from newer variants of covid then getting infected by the newer variants of covid?

Can someone explain?

Comment: Related https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/25390/is-there-a-benefit-of-a-covid-19-vaccination-if-one-had-covid-19-before

Comment: I'd recommend that you look up just how many changes from the original (Wuhan-Hu-1) these variants have.  Most don't have a lot...